# Finding specific <td> using XPath

Tags: ruby, xpath, nokogiri

I have a table and in the table there is this:

```
<table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="0" width="100%" border="0">
<tr>

<td colspan="7" class="csoGreen" width="120%"><b class="white">Accounts and Payment   Methods</b></td>
</tr>
<input type="hidden" name="pageNum" value=""/>
<input type="hidden" name="reload" value=""/>

<tr class="tableCellHeader">
<td nowrap="nowrap"><b></b></td>
<td nowrap="nowrap"><b>Account Number
<br/><br/><span id="accountToggle" style="color:#ff0000"></span></b></td>
<td nowrap="nowrap"><b><center>Amount Due</center></b></td>
<td nowrap="nowrap"><b><center>Due Date</center></b></td>

<td nowrap="nowrap"><b>Enter/Edit<br/>Payment<br/>Amount<span class="red">*</span></b></td>
<td nowrap="nowrap"><b>Enter/Edit<br/>Payment<br/>Date<span class="red">*</span></b></td>
<td nowrap="nowrap"><b>Please select a Payment Method<span class="red">*</span></b></td>
```

Now I wrote this and it works:

```
account_overview_tag.xpath("//td[contains(descendant::center, 'Amount Due')]")
```

However, I want to test that it is a specific td for instance

```
account_overview_tag.xpath("//td[2][contains(descendant::center, 'Amount Due')]")
```

How do I get my XPATH expression to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<td>` that contains your *Amount Due* is actually the third child so this:

```
account_overview_tag.xpath("//td[2][contains(descendant::center, 'Amount Due')]")
```

will give you a `nil` to indicate that nothing was matched. This however:

```
account_overview_tag.xpath("//td[3][contains(descendant::center, 'Amount Due')]")
```

will give you the node you're looking for. You could also be a little more specific by including the `<tr>` in your XPath with something like this:

```
//tr[@class="tableCellHeader"]/td[3][contains(descendant::center, "Amount Due")]
```